# Экранирование текста в блоге

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных, экранирование

Есть довольно тривиальная задача, но какого-то универсального рецепта пока не нашел.

Итак. Пользователь в блоге вводит текст, текст сохраняется в базе и выводится на странице блога. Все бы хорошо, но возникают вопросы с тегами HTML - с одной стороны, хочется предоставить достаточно свободы пользователю для оформления текста, чтобы он мог вставить, например, ролик с youtube. Но, с другой стороны, не дать пользователю нарушить всю разметку на сайте, встроить какой-то вредный javascript и т.д.

Допустим, мы экранируем все символы, а потом "разэкранируем" теги вроде i, b, h1 и т.д. Но что делать со скриптами?

Еще нюанс, хочется дать возможность редактировать текст прямо на той же странице, где он и лежит - взять текст из контейнера, подменить его инпутом с этим текстом - задача не сложная. Но у нас уже одни символы экранированы, другие нет - экранировать все заново значит окончательно испортить текст.

Какие подходы вы используете и какие считаете лучшими?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы решить вопрос с незакрытыми тегами в PHP5 есть библиотека [tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.tidy.php). Она предназначена для того чтобы преобразовывать контент в валидный формат (html, xhtml). А, также, умеет проставлять закрывающие теги если их где-то нет.

Для того чтобы заблокировать возможность использования каких-то тегов и их некоторых атрибутов можно использовать библиотеку [Jevix](http://jevix.ru/project/). Это фильтр html-контента. Умеет вырезать теги, атрибуты, блоки тегов. Плюс, как бонус, умеет делать [типографическую](http://typograf.ru/) обработку текста.

Comment: Ну если уж затрагивать язык программирования, то мне интереснее скорее Python и Django. Конечно, можно использовать библиотеки, вроде BeautyfulSoup, но хочется узнать какое-то общее решение, стратегию, если угодно.

Пока варианты - вырезать все теги кроме "дозволеных" и затем проверять корректность разметки с помощью библиотек или вообще использовать другой язык разметки.

Comment: К сожалению, по Python и Django ничего сказать не могу. Не использую.

На счет стратегии: юзер отправляет блогозапись; сервер принимает контент, закрывает неумышленно/умышленно незакрытые теги, вырезает "лишний" контент, и пишет отфильтрованный вариант в базу.

Comment: Записать в базу это половина вопроса. Например, в тексте попался урл. Показывать его, разумеется, надо в виде настоящего кликабельного урла, но для редактирования лучше показывать обычную текстовую ссылку. Какой вариант хранить в базе? Когда производить обработку текста - перед тем как показать или перед тем как отдать на редактирование? На чьей стороне - клиента или сервера?

Comment: Разумеется, В базе нужно хранить отфильтрованный контент. Фильтровать его нужно перед записью в базу. Зачем каждый раз при выводе нагружать сервер фильтрацией. Пользовательский вариант нужен только если в перспективе интересует анализ ошибок пользовательского ввода.

На счет урлов: на мой взгляд лучше этот случай отдать на откуп пользователю. Обычно, редактор блогозаписей предполагает как минимум какую-то панель инструментов, где и должна быть кнопка для оборачивания куска текста в ссылку. Кроме того, часто, такие вещи делаются через JavaScript-библиотеки типа TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких уникальных вещей как  javascript код - лучше использовать специальные кнопки, где уже, после `preg_match` например, разрешать или запрещать код.

Для  всего остального использовать `strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )` c Вашим списком  разрешенных тегов  `$allowable_tag`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам так не нравятся bb-коды, напишите свой вариант. Общая мысль в том, что пользователь не работает с html напрямую, а лишь размечает, что в тексте преобразовывать в html. А при обработке текста (выводе на страницу) преобразуются лишь те конструкции, которые удовлетворяют неким "правилам безопасности".